# What is the correct name for those matrices where $M{i,j}$ = 1 if i = j, 0 o.w.?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

Is there a name for matrices of this form?

$T\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}, T_{i,j}=
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ 
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & i=j \\
 0 & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}$

Such as these:

$\begin{array}{cccc}
 \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 0 \\
 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 0 \\
 0 \\
 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
\end{array}$

Comment: Since the entries are $T_{i,j}=\delta_{i,j}$ one could maybe call such a matrix a "Kronecker delta matrix", although I don't believe this is a popular or commonly used naming of such a matrix.

Comment: There is no standard terminology, so whatever term you use you will have to explain it.   I might  call them "rectangular identity matrices" , taking care to explicitly define the term.

Comment: I like the Kronecker Delta Matrix, and yes I will keep in mind it is non-standard. Can I call the question answered?